# Form inheritance in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am facing a situation in Spring MVC application where I have a form common to all pages. So, I took that form in a separate jsp page and included that page in other jsp pages. Form is simple:

```
   <form:form method="POST" commandName="coachingDomain" action="searchForm">

    <form:input path="coachingName" placeholder="Search for coaching" />

    <button type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
</form:form>
```

Now the scene is when I run the application, the server is not able to find the binding of *coachingDomain* in the controller. To make it more clear, suppose the form is present in page A1 and is included in page A2. In A2 controller, I have bind coachingDomain like given below:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("coachingDomain",
            new CoachingDomain());
    return "welcome";
}
```

But bind error still appeared. It seems to me the server was trying to find the controller of A1 page first. So, I created A1 controller (as abstract) and made A2 extend A1 controller. Then, I placed the same code in A1. But still the same error was there.

My A1 and A2 controllers are:

```
   public abstract class A1 {

public void showPage1(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("A1 called");
    modelMap.addAttribute("coachingDomain",
            new CoachingDomain());
     }
 }

  @Controller
  @RequestMapping(value = "/A2.html")
 public class A2 extends A1 {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("A2 called");
            showPage1(modelMap, request, response);
    modelMap.addAttribute("searchCoachingDomain",
            new SearchCoachingDomain());
    return "A2";
     }
   }
```

My jsp pages are:

A1.jsp:

```
    <body>
   <form:form method="POST" commandName="coachingDomain" action="searchForm">

    <form:input path="coachingName" placeholder="Search for coaching" />

    <button type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
</form:form>    
  </body>
```

A2.jsp:

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/root.jsp"%>
```

And the error is:

```
       Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'coachingDomain' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
```

There are inheritance examples given in internet but I am not able to make how to to make a form common to all jsp pages. One approach which I think of may be using Javascript where I would bind the submit button with JS function and make a call to required URL. But I was hoping if the same can be achieved by using Spring MVC @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) technique. Please suggest me out here...

Comment: can you post more of your controller and the error you're getting?

Comment: I have added the code and error as you asked...